# Register address stored in another register (PIC18F45K50)

Tags: assembly, pic, mplab

I have the following scenario using a [PIC18F45K50](https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/PIC18F45K50):

I have the value of `0x71` stored in the register `0x50`.
And I have a value of `0x05` stored in the register `0x71`.

How can I access the value stored in `0x71` (in this example `0x05`)just by using the register `0x50`?

The purpose of this is to have a list of registers with literal values inside them.

For example:

```
0x71 has b'1010'<br>
0x72 has b'1100'<br>
0x73 has b'1000'<br>
```

And to keep track of the current register inside `0x50`, so that I can increment this value and go from `0x71` to `0x72`.

Comment: Sounds like you need indirect addressing. Consult section 7.7.6 of the [manual](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/39500a.pdf).